# Safely starting and stopping a thread owned by a class

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

If I have a class running its own thread, I almost always try to write it like the following, with the thread started by the constructor. The reason for this is that an object can never be constructed on multiple threads, so there is never a danger of two threads trying to start the thread. This class prints a message every second until asked to stop, for example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

class a_thread
{
public:
    explicit a_thread(const std::string& msg)
    : _msg(msg)
    , _stop(false)
    , _t(&a_thread::thread_main, this)
    {
    }

    ~a_thread()
    {
        stop();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
        if (!_stop)
        {
            _stop = true;
            l.unlock();
            _cv.notify_all();
            if (_t.joinable())
                _t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    // Disable copying (and moving)
    a_thread(const a_thread&) = delete;
    a_thread& operator=(const a_thread&) = delete;

    void thread_main()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto next_print_time = steady_clock::now();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
        while (!_stop)
        {
            const auto now = steady_clock::now();
            if (now >= next_print_time)
            {
                std::cout << _msg << '\n';
                next_print_time = now + seconds(1);
            }
            else
            {
                _cv.wait_until(l, next_print_time);
            }
        }
    }

    std::string _msg;
    bool _stop;
    std::mutex _m;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    std::thread _t;
};
```

However, sometimes it is desirable to defer the starting of the thread, which I implement like so:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

class b_thread
{
public:
    explicit b_thread(const std::string& msg)
    : _msg(msg)
    , _stop(true)
    {
    }

    ~b_thread()
    {
        stop();
    }

    void start()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
        if (_stop)
        {
            _stop = false;
            l.unlock();
            _t = std::thread(&b_thread::thread_main, this);
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
        if (!_stop)
        {
            _stop = true;
            l.unlock();
            _cv.notify_all();
            if (_t.joinable())
                _t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    // Disable copying (and moving)
    b_thread(const b_thread&) = delete;
    b_thread& operator=(const b_thread&) = delete;

    void thread_main()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto next_print_time = steady_clock::now();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
        while (!_stop)
        {
            const auto now = steady_clock::now();
            if (now >= next_print_time)
            {
                std::cout << _msg << '\n';
                next_print_time = now + seconds(1);
            }
            else
            {
                _cv.wait_until(l, next_print_time);
            }
        }
    }

    std::string _msg;
    bool _stop;
    std::mutex _m;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    std::thread _t;
};
```

Until today, I was confident that this code was thread-safe, in the sense that the `stop()` and `start()` functions could be safely called from multiple threads on the same instance of the class. However, I think the following code could result in a thread being destroyed without first being joined:

```
int main()
{
    b_thread b("Hello world!");
    // Let the main thread be called 'Z'
    auto x = std::thread([&b] () { b.start(); }); // Thread X
    auto y = std::thread([&b] () { b.stop(); }); // Thread Y
    b.start();

    x.join();
    y.join();
}
```

If the timing is right then I believe the program could run as follows:

1. Thread X has assigned to `_t`, but `_t` has not yet acquired the mutex in `thread_main()`. `_stop == false` at the time X released mutex  `_m`.
2. Thread Y saw `_stop == false` after acquiring the mutex and therefore it sets `_stop = true` before releasing the mutex. It is now calling `_cv.notify_all()`.
3. Thread Z is able to acquire the mutex in this state, and sees `_stop == true`. It assigns to `_t`, and therefore destroys the thread constructed by X (which hasn't been `join()`ed yet). Badness ensues.

I also often use an atomic bool when my thread loop has a non-interruptible wait in it (for example, a loop calling `poll()`), like so. I believe it exhibits the same bug:

```
void start()
{
    if (_stop.exchange(false))
        _t = std::thread(&b_thread::thread_main, this);
}

void stop()
{
    if (!_stop.exchange(true) && _t.joinable())
        _t.join();
}
```

I'd appreciate thoughts on the following:

1. The `a_thread` class. This is a pattern I use a lot so I'd like to know if it could be improved.
2. Am I correct about the bug in `b_thread`?
3. If so, is there a way to make `b_thread` safe? What about with the atomic bool variant?

Comment: Have you used TSan ThreadSanitizer? Or done clang [static analysis](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html)?

Comment: I hadn't. I've since run this code, and it crashed every time due to a thread being destroyed before being joined, so it's not very difficult to produce this bug. Having chuckled to myself at other posters who think that a particular class's member functions are magically thread-safe, I feel very silly to have done the same with std::thread all this time! Interestingly, tsan didn't give me any diagnostics - I had better luck with helgrind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Don't let multiple threads access a `std::thread` object

Operations on a `std::thread` object are not thread-safe themselves. If you want to do this, you must hold a mutex such that only one thread can ever have access to it. You do have a mutex, but you unlock it before calling `_t.join()` and `_t = std::thread(…)`, which in turn can cause undefined behavior.

Of course, not unlocking the mutex inside `stop()` is problematic, because keeping `_m` locked while calling `_t.join()` will cause a deadlock, as `main_thread()` is also holding the lock when it's not inside the call to `wait_until()`. To solve this issue, you could consider using two mutexes; one for the public API so only one operation can run at a time, and another one to modify `_stop`. The latter one you can unlock before calling `_t.join()`.

Even if you have ensured access to `_t` is properly guarded at all times, I would still not recommend allowing multiple threads access to your `a_thread` and `b_thread` classes. The reason is that you will certainly get undeterministic behavior. If one thread calls `start()` and the other `stop()`, what will the end result be? A running `thread_main()` or nothing? In an actual program, this will almost certainly cause a problem.

## Consider using `std::jthread`

You are not the only one that needs a thread object that properly cleans up after itself and that allows you to request the thread to stop itself. C++20 introduced [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) for this reason. Consider using that instead if possible. The semantics are a bit different though, and while it has the concept of a "stop token" that allows the thread to check whether it needs to stop, it doesn't provide a way to do timed waits on it like with a condition variable. If you want that, you have to provide your own mutex and condition variable.

If you cannot use C++20 yet, then consider whether reimplementing `std::jthread` instead of your `a_thread` and `b_thread` classes. That way, once you can use C++20, it is trivial to switch from your own class to a standard one.

## Using an atomic flag

A `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_flag` only ensures atomic access to that boolean value. If you do:

```
void start()
{
    if (_stop.exchange(false))
         _t = std::thread(&b_thread::thread_main, this);
}
```

Then by the time it tries to assign something to `_t`, other threads might have accessed `_stop` atomically as well. You might think: but surely, if I just set `_stop` to `false`, then no other thread calling `start()` will be able to get `true` from the call to `exchange()`? But that is only true if no thread is calling `stop()`.

So, you still need a proper mutex to ensure only one thread can call  `start()` or `stop()` at any given time. But you can use an atomic flag to signal a running thread to stop, avoiding the need for the thread to hold any mutex.

Note that since C++20, the atomic types have [`wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/wait) and [`notify_all()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/notify_all) member functions, so you can still wait, but you don't need a mutex and condition variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I looked at std::jthread and FYI, it is possible to have a conditional_variable_any notified when a stop_token has a stop requested (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait).

Comment: You still need have a condition variable and a mutex, and the thread calling `request_stop()` should also notify that condition variable. The documentation you linked to shows you how it works exactly when you call `wait()` with a `std::stop_token`.